# How to Resize a Page with TypeScript for Cucumber/Playwright test

Tags: typescript, cucumber, playwright

I have this method:

```
public async openWindow(): Promise<void> {
console.info("driver-manager: get new page ...");
const [newPage] = await Promise.all([(await this.context).waitForEvent("page")]);
console.info("driver-manager: got new page ...");
await newPage.waitForLoadState("networkidle");
this.page = newPage;
```

}

At the `const [newPage] = await ...` line, a window opens on which are two buttons that are not visible and should/need to be for my Cucumber/Playwright test to pass. I'm suspecting my test isn't passing because the buttons are not visible so the test times out at this line and the remaining statements are not executed. I've been experimenting with the code but am not having any luck in getting the window to resize such that the buttons are visible.

I also have this object:

```
const playwrightBrowserResolution = { viewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 } };
```

which I've been trying to use but no success.

Q: how do I resize the window in my code block?

Comment: Whats' the point of `Promise.all` when there's only one promise in it?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code snippet, it looks like the problem isn’t needing to resize (in fact Playwright won’t care about elements being visible until you try to interact with them), but rather that you’re waiting for an event that’s already happened, and not happening again after you started waiting, causing an indefinite wait until it times out.

The solution should be to start waiting on the event before doing the action that causes the new page to be created, so you have a Promise that will be fulfilled when the page is created and can be `await`ed. In other words, you need to:

1. Start waiting for the event and store the promise
2. Perform the action causing the new page to be created
3. `await` the promise to ensure the event happens and finish waiting for it.

See [the Playwright `waitForEvent` docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-wait-for-event) for an example of this.

If you do ever need to [resize the viewport of an individual page](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-set-viewport-size) though, see the linked doc.

Hope that helps!